# Some times Toast is not visible in activity or inside fragment when added inside handler

Tags: android, toast

Requirement is that toast will be show some delay in fragment  so add inside the handler.
But sometime that toast is not visible. There are some loader operations and fragment transaction action before toast.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 100ms\
        Toast.makeText(getActivity,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, 100);
```

Comment: see my answer may be this help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Handler, Timer Task, CountDownTimer, and using for loop too. My favorite is CountDownTimer which is very easy and fast solution.

```
    private long duration = 30000; // 30 seconds
    private long interval = 1000; // 1 seconds

    CountDownTimer cd = new CountDownTimer(duration, interval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
          // This method call every seconds.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          // When 30 seconds completed this method is called.
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    cd.start();
```

You can change duration and interval according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log tag.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms\
        Log.d("MyLogTag", message);
    }
}, 100);
```